# Translating VB.net to C# (configuration manager issue)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, configurationmanager

I'm currently working on translating a VB.net program to C# and I'm having an issue with the process.

I'm trying to do the following with ConfigurationManager :

```
string myNumbers = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ClientNumbers");
```

Where ClientNumbers is a `list<string>` which works in VB.net but presents me with a "Method, delegate or event is expected" error in C#. I'm not sure why that is and I can't seem to find an answer using my Googling skills.

Thanks, in advance, for any assistance.

Comment: should be `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientNumbers"];` There are plenty of resources on SO for this common question.

Comment: Never us the term "Googling" here. Even though you're trying to show that you've attempted some research, the SO community will tear you to shreds *(points to question vote count)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply:

```
string myNumbers = ConfigurationManager.AppSetings["ClientNumber"];
```

you need to use the C# indexer which is a square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the brackets

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientNumbers"];
```

Simply use this link for conversion http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/